# $Z$-matrix properties

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> **[Ciarlet 1.3-2]** Let $A=(a_{ij})$ be a square matrix whose elements satisfy $a_{ii} \geq 0$, $a_{ij}\leq 0$ if $i\neq j$. Show that the following two properties are equivalent.
>
> 1. The matrix $A$ is invertible and the elements of $A^{-1}$ are all non-negative.
> 2. There exists a diagonal matrix $D$, with positive diagonal elements, and a number $\alpha$ such that
>    $$\alpha > 0\;\; \mbox{ and }\;\; \langle v,DAv\rangle \geq \alpha\langle v,v\rangle,\;\; \forall\; v\in\mathbb{R}^n.$$
>    In other words, the matrix $DA$ (in general, not symmetric) is also 'positive definite'.

Comment: As the example $B=\left(\matrix{0&1\\-1&0} \right)$ shows, you can't deduce that a real matrix is symmetric when the corresponding  "quadratic" form (which should not be called quadratic form, since the matrix is not symmetric) takes real values. This is only true in the complex case.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it, why you posted that. :S

Comment: Because $(x,Bx)=0$ for every $x$, but $B$ is not symmetric. If you want, $(x,(I+B)x)=\|x\|^2$, but $I+B$ is not positive definite.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it yet. The example of matrix $B$ is for the route 1. to 2. or 2. to 1. ?

Comment: That's for your "in other words". It is not true in the real case. Only in the complex case.

Comment: (-1) for no own work or motivation.

Comment: Hi TMM, I will hope that in the same way that you gave me (-1) "for no own work or motivation.", you will give (+1) to user1551 by all her/his "own work or motivation." Because he/she knows how responses to the questions, that you don't have idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a cleaned-up proof of Theorem 2.5.3 of Horn and Johnson's ***Topics in Matrix Analysis***. It doesn't seem to be the shortest proof, but it comes in handy.

Let $A = aI-P$, where $a=\max_i a_{ii}\ge 0$. Hence $P$ is a (entrywise) nonnegative matrix. Let $u$ be the Perron vector of $P$. That is, $u\ge 0$ (entrywise) and $u$ is an eigenvector such that $Pu=\rho(P)u$, where $\rho(\cdot)$ denotes spectral radius. Then
\begin{equation}
Au = au-Pu = (a-\rho(P))u.\tag{1}
\end{equation}

Suppose property 2 holds.

1. By considering $\langle u, DAu\rangle$, show that $a>\rho(P)$.
2. Let $X=\frac1a P$. Hence $\rho(X)<1$. Express $A^{-1}$ as a power series of $X$ and show that $A^{-1}$ is nonnegative.

Now suppose property 1 holds.

1. From equation $(1)$, we get $u = (a-\rho(P))A^{-1}u$. Show that $a>\rho(P)$.
2. Let $E$ be an entrywise positive matrix. By [Perron-Frobenius theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem), $P+E$ has a positive Perron vector $x>0$. Hence $(aI-P-E)x = (a-\rho(P+E))x$. Show that when $E$ is sufficiently small, $Ax>0$ entrywise.
3. Let $D_2 = \operatorname{diag}(x)$. Show that $AD_2$ is [strictly diagonally dominant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonally_dominant_matrix).
4. Hence property 1 also holds if we replace $A$ by $(AD_2)^T$. Therefore, by similar reasoning, there exists a positive diagonal matrix $D_1$ such that $(AD_2)^TD_1$ is strictly diagonally dominant.
5. Note that $S=D_1AD_2 + D_2A^TD_1$ is a real symmetric matrix. Hence all its eigenvalues are real. Show that it is strictly diagonally dominant, and hence by [Gerschgorin disc theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin%27s_circle_theorem), it is positive definite. In turn, $DA + A^TD$ is positive definite too, where $D=D_2^{-1}D_1$. Now property 2 follows.

Comment: user1551 thanks so much, you really rulez on this!! The ideas that you gave to me (on this and an others questions), really they help me in my studies. :D

Comment: How I can show that $D_1AD_2 + D_2A^TD_1$ is positive definite? Thanks in advance

Comment: Also, when I get $DA + A^TD$, I can prove that $\langle v, Dv\rangle > 0$, but I don't know how to prove that $\langle v, Dv\rangle \geq \alpha\langle v, v\rangle$

Comment: For your 1st question, $S=D_1AD_2+D_2A^TD_1$ is real symmetric. Hence its eigenvalues are real. If you can prove that $S$ is strictly diagonally dominant (abbv. "sdd" below), then by [Gerschgorin disc theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin%27s_circle_theorem), all eigenvalues of $S$ are positive and hence $S$ is positive definite. Now $AD_2$ is sdd by step 3 and $D_2A^TD_1$ is sdd by step 4. So, you need to explain why $D_1AD_2$ is sdd. For your 2nd question, note that $\langle v,DAv\rangle=\langle v,Sv\rangle$. (Why?)

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I know how to prove that $\langle v,DAv\rangle=\langle v,Sv\rangle$, then $\langle v,DAv\rangle > 0$, but how do I can prove that $\langle v, DAv\rangle \geq \alpha\langle v, v\rangle$?. Thanks for this

Comment: @FASCH You don't prove $\langle v,DAv\rangle\ge\alpha\langle v,v\rangle$ directly. Instead, prove that $\langle v,(DA+A^TD)v\rangle\ge2\alpha\langle v,v\rangle$. (There's a small mistake in my previous comment. What you should show is $\langle v,DAv\rangle=\frac12\langle v,(DA+A^TD)v\rangle$, **not** $\langle v,DAv\rangle=\langle v,Sv\rangle$)

Comment: How do I can prove $\langle v,(DA+A^TD)v\rangle\ge2\alpha\langle v,v\rangle$? I chance $A = \alpha I + P$ in $\langle v,(DA+A^TD)v\rangle$, but I can not prove $\langle v,(DA+A^TD)v\rangle\ge2\alpha\langle v,v\rangle$ :S Thanks in advance

Comment: @FASCH This is actually an instance of a more general fact: for any positive definite matrix $M$, there is some $\beta>0$ such that $\langle v,Mv\rangle\ge\beta\langle v,v\rangle$. (Why? What properties or features does a positive definite matrix possess?)

Comment: Sorry, I am searching, but I haven't found the propeties for get $\langle v,Mv\rangle\ge\beta\langle v,v\rangle$ :S

Comment: Could you please recommend me a book, where I can look this result?

Comment: @FASCH I haven't any textbook at hand, so I don't know which to recommend. But the key is that $\langle v,Mv\rangle \ge \lambda_\min(M)\langle v,v\rangle$, where $\lambda_\min(M)$ is the minimum eigenvalue of $M$. The proof is rather straightforward.

Comment: Thanks, for this hints, for Rayleigh quotient, I can prove that $\langle v,(DA+A^TD)v\rangle \ge \lambda_{\min}(DA+A^TD)\langle v,v\rangle$. Now, I must to prove  that $\lambda_{\min}(DA+A^TD) \geq 2\alpha$? If it is true, I have problem with the matrix $D$, because: $\lambda_{\min}(DA+A^TD) = 2\lambda_{\min}(D)(\alpha - \lambda_{\min}(P))$ and I don't know how obtain the result. Thanks

Comment: Ohh, I finally see my mistake. $\alpha = \lambda_{\min}$. Sorry, I confused $\alpha = a = \max_i\{a_{ii}\}$. Thanks, for the patience.

Comment: @FASCH Yes, we **set** $\alpha$ to $\frac12\lambda_\min(DA+A^TD)$, so that $\langle v,DAv\rangle=\frac12\langle v,(DA+A^TD)v\rangle \ge \frac12[\lambda_{\min}(DA+A^TD)]\langle v,v\rangle=\alpha\langle v,v\rangle$. This is a bit like showing that some function $f$ is continuous using a $\epsilon-\delta$ proof, in which we **set** $\delta$ to an appropriate quantity that is dependent on $\epsilon$, so that for any given $\epsilon>0$, $|f(x+h)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ whenever $h<\delta$.